# How to connect a NAS device that all virtual machines can access in ESXi 5.1?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Basically we have a 29TB data store that we would like all of our VMs to be able to read and write, and we want VMware to treat it as one large storage volume.

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: You're asking two different questions: 1. Q: How can all your VM's read/write to it? A: Set it up like you would any other file server (CIFS/SMB, NFS). 2. Q: How can VMware (presumably you mean vSphere) use it as a datastore? A: You have to present it to vSphere as a datastore, but then you can't directly use it as a file server for your virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to use the storage as VM disks, or do you want to be able to mount the same share inside all VMs?

If the first, create a NFS share and add it as storage on the VMware host. If the second, you need to map the share using whatever method available in the OS each VM is running. Which I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The exact same way you would with physical servers sharing storage. If they are *nix I'd just mount it via NFS, if it's Windows you will need to use it as a shared drive or iSCSI LUN but if you go with iSCSI you have to deal with clustering etc.

VMware does not come into the picture.

Comment: As in just mount it as a NFS datastore in each separate VM?

Comment: Do you want the ESX server to see it as a single large volume or each individual VM to see it? They are two different things. One is a datastore that holds VMs, the other will be a shared drive you'd map inside each virtual machine's OS.

Answer (score -1):

This is a link to an article I wrote a while back that I believe will help:

http://www.xpertnotes.net/add-qnap-nfs-share-to-esxi-as-a-datastore/

Comment: ServerFault prefers answers to have content, not just links to content (bitrot happens). Please update this with at least a summary of how this will help the questioner.